# C int array and pointer interaction

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The following code...

```
int array[] = {17, 18, 19};
printf("Location of array: %p\n",       array);
printf("   Value of array: %d\n",       *array);
printf("    Size of array: %d bytes\n", sizeof(array));
```

Produces the output

```
Location of array: 0x7ffd0491c574
   Value of array: 17
    Size of array: 12 bytes
```

When I use variable array on the second line, it refers to the location of the "17". When I use it on the third like, it dereferences the pointer and prints out the number 17. Those, I understand.

On the last line, it prints out "12 bytes" as the size of the array. Why doesn't it print out 4 bytes, since in the previous two uses of the same variable, it seems to exclusively refer to the zero index of the array? How does `sizeof` know to look at the remainder of the array, instead of just printing out 4 bytes (as it would if I ran `(sizeof(*array)`)?

Comment: `array` is the whole array, `*array` (aka. `array[0]`), is the first element

Comment: Re "*[the two previous uses of `array`] seems to exclusively refer to the zero index of the array?*", No, only `*array` referred to the first index of the array, and so would `sizeof(*array)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When passed to `sizeof`, an array name doesn't decay into pointer, so the whole array size is found.

In the first case, it decays into pointer to the first element and the address is printed.

In the second case, we dereference the address, which is basically the value at the address pointed by the array name, namely the first element.

#### Why doesn't it print out 4 bytes?

From the C standard **$6.5.3.4 (sizeof operator)**

> When  applied  to  an operand that has **array type, the result is the
>   total number of bytes in the array.**

This answers your question why when passed an array name it shows the number of bytes. Here the array has 3 elements and each of size `sizeof int` or 4 Bytes in your system and so the `total size = 3*4 = 12`

#### What is `*array`?

`*array` is nothing other than `array[0]`. `array` decays into pointer to the first element of the array and then we dereference it. What is the value that is there? That is the value 17.

#### Why `sizeof(*array)=4`?

Well if you remember `array` is an array of 3 integers. So ofcourse the value contained in it is of type `int`. In your system `sizeof int` is 4 bytes. That's why you will get 4 as a result `sizeof *array` .

#### How `sizeof` works?

`sizeof` is implemented by the compiler. For non-VLA type of objects `sizeof` is a constant which is resolved compile time. But in case of VLA the array size is known at run time and that generates the result. So this is an expression for VLA.

Comment: Can you please provide the link you got this information from?

Comment: @surendranath.: Which information are you talking about? The standard draft is openly available. The quote is from there. Rest of the things have been acquired over time not within 5 minutes when the question is published. Array decaying is pretty common notion. The C standard is N1570. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
sizeof(number of array elements * sizeof data_type)
sizeof(3 * 4)
```

sizeof `int` generally `4` bytes.
sizeof gives 12 bytes.

Comment: "*`sizeof(3 * 4)`*": well, well ... - this would evaluate to the size of exactly *one* `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Here array is the pointer to an array of 3 integers, so if you are the printing size of the array, it will give you 12 bytes as each integer takes 4 bytes.

As you know array will have starting location of the array, now you are printing integer at the address "array" by using format specifier %d. It will print integer stored in first 4 bytes of the array,i.e. 17.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(*array)` would give you `sizeof(int)` (seemingly 4 on your computer).

`sizeof(array)` gives 12 because `sizeof(*array)` gives 4, and you have 3 of these (int), 3 x 4.

`array` is an area in memory where the 3 integer are stored

```
<int0><int1><int2>
^
array
```

`sizeof(array)` gives the size of that space occupied by that area.

Mentioning `array` as itself in, for instance, `int *p = array;` stores the address of `array` in the pointer `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C are not exactly pointers, which is used to be in early days. Array names are decay into pointer based on the use of identifier(variable).  Array names were pointer which caused problem with structure containing the array member, storing the pointer in array eventually lead to problem with structure members. So it was decided by the author of C to make array as name to location rather than the pointer some location. When used with * it will decay into pointer. Which allow us to use the array as `a[i], i[a], *(a+i)` .

Comment: "*which is used to be in early days*" when were those days?

Comment: @alk 1969. started with BCPL which was adopted to C. but when `structure` was added, it became a issue.

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof()` is a operand evaluated at *compile time*. The compiler knows the size, because it creates the array.